# Tag-IT autocomplete is not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I am trying to use Tag-It plugin for tags on my blog, but I have encountered a problem. My autocompletion is not working, if I use available tags option it completes just fine, but if i try to use Ajax nothing happens, or atleast on client side. My method triggers and returns right data but nothing is whispered.
Script:

```
$("#tag_input").tagit({

    // Options
    fieldName: "skills",
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"],
    autocomplete: {
       source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "@Url.Action("SearchTags", "Post")",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
              query: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
              response(data);
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 3,
    } ,
```

My function in controller:

```
 public JsonResult SearchTags(string query)
        {
            TagDao td = new TagDao();
            List<String> tags= td.getTagNames(query);
            return Json(tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is incomplete. There is no closure on the tagIt function.  Can you include the rest?  Also the `url:` line looks invalid.  The value is not a valid single string.  Is this pure JavaScript?  Or is it run through a preprocessor?  Have you tried using the JS debugger in your browser?

Comment: Url seems fine to me, because the method is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in solution, it was caused by "jsonp" type. When i used only "json" it is working just fine.